# Firefix CSS animation feep firing

Tags: jquery, firefox, animation, css-animations

Hi I am having difficulties with some problem on my site.
http://au-urbanfuture.org/portfolios

The portfolio page has an animation which each box animates when scrolling down if they are not initially on viewport.  The default all the boxes opacity is set 0. The js determines which boxes are on viewport and adds class shown and gives them opacity 1. The animation runs smoothly on Chrome, Safari..etc but Firefox keeps firing the opacity animation on every action. When you scroll down, when hover, when hover out

If you can you help me the solve the issue, I would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Ok I just solved the problem. The animation was keep firing because the original box element has animation-duration and this was not actually overridden by animate class for some reason. Make sure you have only one animation feature on your object